Increase the range of tablet mode detection - Ubuntu 24.04
recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on Lenovo Yoga 7 14ARP8.
The touchscreen mostly works, the current issue is the switch to tablet mode.
On my previous Yoga 14ITL9 (Ubuntu 22.04), the switch occurs as soon as I flip the screen over 180 degrees. That means the physical screen gets disabled and only the touchscreen/stylus works. In the current laptop, the switch happens only after 330 degrees (almost fully rotated).
I've tried this:
https://github.com/alesya-h/linux_detect_tablet_mode
but when debugging, it only confirmed my observations, the event happens only when almost fully flipped.
Is there a way for the switch to the tablet mode to be triggered from 180 degrees?
Thanks!
